# React.Component class constructor runs once without console.log?

Tags: reactjs, constructor

This React.Component class constructor seems to be run 2 times for one instance, in a weird way.

Apparently:

1. the counter is incremented `0` -> `1` *without* a console.log output
2. the counter is incremented `1` -> `2` *with* a console.log output

Is this true ? Why does the console show `2` and not `1` ?

```
import React from 'react';

var instanceCount = 0;
console.log('root:', instanceCount);

class App extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log('before change:', instanceCount);
        instanceCount++;
        console.log('after change:', instanceCount);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <>test</>
        );
    }
}

export default App;

// console output:
//   root: 0
//   before change: 1
//   after change: 2
```

In contrast, a "normal" javascript class behaves as expected:

```
var instanceCount = 0;
class SomeClass {
    constructor(props) {
        console.log('before change:', instanceCount);
        instanceCount++;
        console.log('after change:', instanceCount);
    }
}
var instance = new SomeClass();

// console output:
//   before change: 0
//   after change: 1
```

Comment: Try to put your `var instanceCount = 0; console.log('root:', instanceCount);` inside the `class App extends React.Component {`, but before the `render()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because you are using [StrictMode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper):

> ...
> This is done by **intentionally double-invoking the following functions**:
>
> **Class component: `constructor`** ...

The mode invokes the `constructor` twice, and React also silences the log:

> Starting with React 17, React automatically modifies the console
> methods like `console.log()` to silence the logs in the second call to
> lifecycle functions. ...

```
// Remove StrictMode
ReactDOM.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

[image: Edit nostalgic-currying-cn7ht]