# how to calculate default value for react js state hook with a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm doing something like this:

```
function App() {

  const [state1, setState1] = useState([1,1,1,1,1,1]);
  const [state2, setState2] = useState(MyFunction());

  return (
    <div className="App">
    <button onClick={() => setState1([1,2,3,4,5,6])}>test</button>
    </div>
  );
}

const MyFunction= () => {
  alert("MyFunction");
  return 5;
}
```

The strange thing is that the line `alert("MyFunction");` is triggered 2 times on load and 2 times on every click on test button.

I'm very new to React.js and I don't understand this behavior.

Comment: Are you by chance using strict mode? Ie, do you render a `<React.StrictMode>` near the top of your app?

Comment: In [strict mode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html), components are deliberately double-rendered to help identify misuse of the lifecycle hooks. So while normally you'd get one render when the component mounts, and then one every time you set state, you'll get two instead in strict mode. This only occurs in development builds of your app, not production builds.

Comment: To set an initial state value based on a function call, use `useEffect` and pass an empty dependency array (which means the passed function will only run once, and you can do basic "on mount" stuff inside): https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-glitter-gqf99?file=/src/App.js

Comment: without strict mode it run only one time on load (as expected) and 1 time when I change another state variable, I don't undertand this second behavior

Comment: Changing state causes the function to rerender. When it rerenders, the code runs from the top of the App function to the bottom, and one of the things you do in there is call `MyFunction()`. you then pass the return value of `MyFunction()` into `useState`. This only matters on the first render, but with the way you've written it, it happens on every render.

Comment: When state changes, the component is re-rendered. This means the function runs again, which means `const [state2, setState2] = useState(MyFunction());` runs again, which means the function in question runs again. Keep in mind that React is just JavaScript (granted, with some JSX magic added).

Comment: @ChrisG useState(MyFunction()) is called when the component is re-rendered. BUT the value of state2 is re-initializad with the return of the function every time?

Comment: No, of course not, that would defeat the whole point of having state. The `useState` function takes care of this.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question:

> how to calculate default value for react js state hook with a function?

[useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initial-state) allows a function as a 'initial state factory', like e.g.:

```
const [ state, setState ] = useState( function(){ return Math.random(); } );
```

So if you want to use your `MyFunction` as a factory, just use it this way:

```
const [ state2, setState2 ] = useState( MyFunction );
```

#### why is MyFunction called on every click ?

A React functional component is just a javascript function.

React decides when to call this function, which is basically whenever something changes. A call of some `setState()` is one reason why
React will call the function of the functional component again (your `App()` function in this case).

But I suggest you consider the `App()` function to be called *"whenever React wants to call it"*, or *"all the time, again and again"*. Meaning you should not
rely on when the function of the functional component is called, you should instead rely on the guarantees which React makes
regarding when the state is up-to-date, specifically [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect), [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate), ...

`MyFunction()` is just a function call, which is inside the `App()` function call, so - of course - `MyFunction()` is called
whenever `App()` is called (which is "again and again").

#### Why is the `alert()` called twice ?

The functional component is called 2 times in [Strict Mode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html).
This causes unexpected behavior only if you aren't using React as it is supposed to be used (which is something that just happens for React-beginners).

If you are using React in the intended way, you should not have to care about if the function is called once, twice or multiple times. The only thing that counts is what the state is.

See also e.g. [React.Component class constructor runs once without console.log?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69235754/react-component-class-constructor-runs-once-without-console-log)